# Django: Handling an uploaded SQLite file

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm working on a simple Django application in which the user upload a SQLite file; the data is read and added to the main database (PostgreSQL).
My idea is to use two databases, one for the main application and the other to manage the uploaded file  (the structure is always the same so I can create models for it).

What do you think about this solution? Is it possible to dynamically change the settings.py file for the second database so I can modify the path and easily read data inside it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Django supports [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/) in one project, you can set up postgres as default DB and sqlite as secondary (just for upload).

Comment: Do you think that I can change the "name" option to use the uploaded sqlite file?

Comment: I think you can put file in some predefined location, and use it.

Comment: I don't believe it would be good practice to do this.  Django is multithreaded in nature, so if two users upload a file at once, you can't be certain you will be editing the correct database. This will probably appear to work using ./manage.py runserver because that is single threaded, but it will most likely fall over in production.